# Python for loop over non-numeric folders in hdf5 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, hdf5, h5py

I want to pull the numbers from a *.HDF5* data file, which is in folders with increasing numbers:

Folder_001, Folder_002, Folder_003, ... Folder_100.

In each folder, the data I want to pull has same name: 'Time'. So in order for me to pull the numbers from each folders, I am trying to use for loop over the name of folders to pull numbers in files; yet, still can't figure out how to structure the code. I did the following

```
f = h5.File('name.h5'.'r')
folders = list(f.keys())
for i in folders:
    dataset_folder = f['i']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = h5.File('name.h5', 'r')    # comma
groups = f.keys()
adict = {}
for key in groups:
    agroup = f[key]
    ds = agroup['Time']    # a dataset
    arr = ds[:]            # download the dataset to array
    adict[key] = arr
```

Now `adict` should be a dictionary with keys like 'Folder_001', and values being the respective `Time` array.   You could also collect those arrays in a list.